# Equation to a level surface

Tags: calculus

Could someone please help me with the following question:

> Consider the function $g(x,y,z)=\ln(x^2-y+z^2)$. Find an equation of the level surface of the function through the point $(-1,2,1)$ which does not have $\ln$. Hint: first find $g(-1,2,1).$

When I sub in the points I get $$g(-1,2,1)=\ln(1-2+1)=\ln(0)=\text{undefined}$$. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks,
bbelson01

Comment: Welcome to MSE, please use latex for the mathematics text. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Yes, I agree with you unless I'm missing something erroneous. Also note that $(\nabla g)(-1, 2, 1)$ is undefined too. There must be an error in the point $(-1, 2, 1)$ or perhaps a typo in $g$ itself.

Comment: Can't you accept the paraboloid $y=x^2+z^2$ which is the iso-surface for level $-\infty$ ?

Comment: I think @YvesDaoust has the right view, it is a $-\infty$ level surface.

Comment: @YvesDaoust could you please elaborate on your answer? I'm at a complete loss.

Comment: The second part to the question is: describe the level surface of g(x,y,z) in general. Classify the level surface through the point (-1,2,1) first then explain how the other level surfaces are similar/different. Consider how key features such as vertices, centres and axes passing through the centre (where they exist) are similar/different.

Comment: Appreciate your responses as well.

Comment: @Mattos Please use $\rm\LaTeX$ so OP doesn't get the wrong idea. :D

Answer (score 2):

$$\ln(x^2-y+z^2)=\ln(x_0^2-y_0+z_0^2)$$
can be rewritten
$$y=x^2+z^2+(y_0-x_0^2-z_0^2).$$

It remains the same paraboloid of revolution, with the apex moving along the axis $y$.